# How to load child component only when mat expansion panel is expanded?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I have mat accordion in which I am dynamically creating expansion panels and its content components

```
<mat-accordion>
<Mat-expansion-panel ngfor>
<Header>
<Custom component with some input for api call>
```

I want to render and call api inside custom component only when expansion panel is expanded.

Currently api is getting called for each panel even if it is close.

Answer (score 1):

Move the content to the specific ng-template `matExpansionPanelContent`.
(https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanelContent)

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    My Header
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    My lazy content
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```